# Converting raster GeoTIFF or NetCDF to image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, raster-conversion, google-earth-engine-python-api, rioxarray

I try to convert raster `tif` or `netcdf` file to `ee.Image` Google Earth Engine object in Python. The `netcdf` raster testing data (5-bands) is in this [link](https://github.com/tuyenhavan/Course_Data/blob/main/testdata.nc). Here I converted the first band from raster file to `ee.Image` but throwed errors indicating invalid data types.

```
import rioxarray
import ee
import xarray as xr
ds=rioxarray.open_rasterio("testdata.nc", masked=True)
# Rename 
ds.name="raster"
# Select the first band and convert it to GEE image
band=ds.isel(band=0)

band=ee.Image(band)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a server-side object (`ee.Image`) with a client-side file. Please read [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) for understanding how GEE works.

Since `ee.Image` is a server-side function, check [what kind of inputs it accepts](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image):

> **ee.Image**
>
> An object to represent an Earth Engine image. This
> constructor accepts a variety of arguments:
>
> - A string: an EarthEngine asset id,
> - A string and a number: an EarthEngine asset id and version,
> - A number or ee.Array: creates a constant image,
> - A list: creates an image out of each list element and combines them into a single image,
> - An ee.Image: returns the argument,
> - Nothing: results in an empty transparent image.

That's why you get invalid data type error, since a local file isn't a valid input.

**Solution**: upload your file to GEE and then call the asset.

You can either [upload the raster to Earth Engine with command line tools](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line#upload) or use the [Asset manager](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager), then you can access to the file with the asset ID or path.